# Rails belongs_to many but parent only has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models, `interaction`, `contact`, and `company`. A `company` has_many `contacts`, and an `interaction` has_one `contact`, and a `contact` can belong_to one `company` but can belong_to many interactions. How can I represent that in rails?

It makes sense that a `contact` has the `company_id` and an `interaction` has the `contact_id`, but then you can't call `interaction.contact` because rails sees that as

```
SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."interaction_id" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

where `$1` is my `contact_id` in `interaction` which doesn't do what I want, which is something like

```
SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This arrangement fits your use case:

```
class Company

  has_many :contacts

end

class Contact

  belongs_to :company
  has_many :interactions

end

class Interaction

  belongs_to :contact

end
```

You could also explore [bi-directional associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), but that's more of an advanced topic.